# Accidentally cancelled python's "pip" upgrade in the middle of the operation now pip is malfunctioning

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, pip, failed-installation

I was trying to update python's pip command through the command line and accidentally pressed *ctrl+c* which cancelled the upgrade mid-process.

As soon as I realised what had happened I tried to rerun the command `python -m install --upgrade pip` and I got this error code:

`(Currently running python 3.8.3) on Windows 10 Home`

```
      File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
        return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
      File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
        from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
      File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
        from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
      File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
        from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
      File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
        from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
      File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 21, in <module>
        from pip._vendor.packaging.utils import canonicalize_name
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor'
```

Is there any way to fix this or should I reinstall python? I had no extra pip libraries installed except the `requests` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pip-on-windows/) guide. I also describe the steps here:

0. Find where your python is located. In Windows it might be located in a path similar to `C:\Users\<your-name>\AppsData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-<minor-version>`
1. Download the [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) script to the directory where your Python is located. You can just copy the content and paste it into a file with the same name
2. Open the terminal (or PowerShell) and change the directory to where your Python is located.
3. run the script as follows: `python get-pip.py`
4. Verify the installation by executing: `pip -V`

Comment: Thank you! That seems to make pip work but it constantly shows `WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (C:\Users\<username>\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages)` whenever I run pip.

Comment: go to the `site-packages` directory and check for directories starting with a tilde (`~`). Specifically, check if you have a directory starting with `~ip`. If so, delete it.